# Trying to open multiple browsers keep geeting an error script wont run

Tags: python

Having an issue when trying to run my script any suggestions. When I run my script I receive an stating " UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 13 of the file /home/maddawg/Scripts/lucky.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)" So when I try to run it from the command line it will not work any advise?

## ! /usr/bin/python3

## lucky.py - Opens several google search results.

```
import requests
import sys
import webbrowser
import bs4
    print('Googling...') # display text while downloading the Google page
res = requests.get('http://google.com/search?q=' + ' '.join(sys.argv[1:]))
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text)

LinkElems = soup.select('.r a')
numOpen = min(5, len(LinkElems))
for i in range(numOpen):
    webbrowser.open('http://google.com/' + LinkElems[i].get('href'))
```

Comment: That warning feels like a red herring, since it's not actually an error. To get more help from this site, though, I'd recommend reading up on how to ask questions here - most of the time you'll want to include the code you're having a problem with, and a more descriptive explanation of the problem rather than "it will not work".

Comment: Okay now i updated it any reason im getting error when i try to run that script?